# How to detect the starting words in text using regular expression?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have text documents in which some lines are started with expression like 1) or i) or ii) and similar kind. I have performed sentence segmentation of text document using punkt sentence tokenizer. But the punkt sentence tokenizer is unable to detect these as sentence boundary. For e.g punkt tokenizer detect this as one sentence:

> (f) With respect to the other matters to be included in the Auditor's Report in accordance with Rule 11 of the Companies (Audit and Auditors) Rules, 2014, in our opinion and to the best of our information and according to the explanations given to us:
>   i) The Company has disclosed the impact of pending litigations on its financial position in its financial statements;
>   I i) The Company did not have any material foreseeable losses on long-term contracts including derivative contracts; 
>   iii) There has been no delay in transferring amounts, required to be transferred, to the Investor Education and Protection Fund by the Company.

I want to further segment each detected sentences using regular expression in python. So how do i detect the i) or iii) in the sentence?

Comment: I don't understand why this question is down-voted by users. I didn't find any answer related to mentioned query that is why i have raised this question. Could anyone who down-voted this question explain their reason for that, so that from next time i will be more careful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
(?i)\b[0-9ivxlcdm]+\)
```

- `(?i)`  : case insensitive
- `\b`    : word boundary
- `[0-9ivxlcdm]+` : 1 or more digits or roman digits
- `\)`    : a closing parenthesis

Comment: Accepted as solution to problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `/^[^\n]+/m`. This should work if you don't have newlines in your sentences.

Answer (score 0):

Able to figure out the regular expression for this substitution.

`r'((\w+)[\)])'` works for this substitution.

Comment: This matches `Auditors) ` in the text, is it really wanted?

Comment: No That will not work...I tried this. Not removal of Auditors) not desired.